# access a submodule of a flax class/module without calling model.apply()

Tags: jax, flax

I have module/class of this kind:

```
class autoencoder(nn.Module):
    
    hidden_dim: int
    z_dim: int
    output_dim: int

    def setup(self):
        
        self.encoder = encoder(self.hidden_dim, self.z_dim)
        self.decoder = decoder(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)

    def __call__(self, x):

        z = self.encoder(x)
        y = self.decoder(z)
        
        return y
```

Here, encoder and decoder are classes defined elsewhere. On occasions, I want to be able to call the individual submodules (e.g. self.encoder or self.decoder) of the module autoencoder, but as I understand they are inaccessible and can only be accessed by calling __ call __ (e.g. via model.apply), which calls both of them, consecutively (which I do also want to do sometimes). I ideally want to keep these submodules bundled together in this module so that when I initialize the model (via model.init), I have the full model and all of it's parameters in one place. (In my actual problem I have 6 submodules so I have simplified things here.)

Can someone tell me how I should approach this?

I've just noticed that this exact problem (even using an autoencoder as an example) is described [here](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/module_lifecycle.html) under 'Future work'. Is there really no current solution to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the module as described https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/flax.linen/module.html#flax.linen.Module.bind

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import flax.linen as nn

class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
  def setup(self):
    self.encoder = nn.Dense(3)
    self.decoder = nn.Dense(5)

  def __call__(self, x):
    return self.decoder(self.encoder(x))

x = jnp.ones((16, 9))
ae = AutoEncoder()
variables = ae.init(jax.random.key(0), x)
model = ae.bind(variables)
z = model.encoder(x)
x_reconstructed = model.decoder(z)
```

Hope this was what you were looking for

Comment: According to [the docs](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/flax.linen/module.html#flax.linen.Module.bind): "Once the variables (and optionally RNGs) are bound to a `Module` it becomes a stateful object. Note that idiomatic JAX is functional and therefore an interactive instance does not mix well with vanilla JAX APIs. `bind()` should only be used for interactive experimentation, and in all other cases we strongly encourage users to use `apply()` instead."